# oracle sql date comparison doesn't work as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table X with 'insert_date' column. This column is od type DATE and contains only one value for all records: "17-JAN-13". I would expect that following query return no results at all:

```
SELECT insert_date
FROM X
  WHERE ("X"."INSERT_DATE" IS NOT NULL
  AND NOT (("X"."INSERT_DATE" = to_date('2013-01-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
  )))
```

But what I'm getting instead is many "17-JAN-13" records.
What's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oracle `DATE` columns contain a time as well (despite their name). Your existing rows probably have a time different than `00:00:00` (which is "assigned" to the date you create with the `to_date()` function).

You need to "remove" the time part of the column using `trunc()`

```
AND NOT (trunc(X.INSERT_DATE) = to_date('2013-01-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
```

although I'd prefer to use `<>` instead of the `NOT` operator:

```
AND (trunc(X.INSERT_DATE) <> to_date('2013-01-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
```

(but that is just a *personal* preference. I think it makes the condition easier to read).

So your complete statement would be:

```
SELECT insert_date
FROM X
  WHERE trunc(X.INSERT_DATE) <> to_date('2013-01-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Comment: How can I extract time part to see what's inside instead of 00:00:00?

Comment: @mnowotka Use `to_char()` with a suitable format mask or change the display settings for your SQL client

Comment: Although `trunc()` will impact index use; I'd prefer `(X.INSERT_DATE < to_date('2013-01-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd') or X.INSERT_DATE >= to_date('2013-01-18', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))`, but it's getting a bit messy...

Comment: @AlexPoole: you can always define an index on `trunc(INSERT_DATE)` which will be used then (provided it sufficiently "reduces" the number of rows returned)

Comment: True, if possibly a bit advanced for this discussion (and still an 'impact' <grin>). Teaching people a model with side-effects feels a little awkward somehow. Also a personal preference I guess *8-)

Comment: The IS NOT NULL predicate is redundant here, as "trunc(NULL) <> to_date('2013-01-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd')" will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

You can either trunc the time part while comparing or else extract only the required part i.e `DD-MON-YYYY` like

```
SELECT insert_date FROM X 
WHERE X.INSERT_DATE IS NOT NULL and to_char(x.INSERT_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') <> '17-JAN-2013';
```